# Spring security- Infinite user session time out with IDP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

Our application is using Spring security SAML for handling user authentication. I have got a requirement to keep the user session alive for infinite period.
Is there a way to set an infinite timeout in Spring SAML for user session time out?

IDP has following configuration, so no problem there.

```
<session-config>

    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>

</session-config>
```

In SP, maxAuthenticationAge is set to 36000 to keep it active for 10 hrs.
Default is 7200. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/websso/WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.html

One solution could be to keep the session alive by making authentication requests in the background periodically(not very sure about this approach), so that it never logs out. Any other idea please?

Comment: Are you really sure you want "infinite"?  That's a recipe for OutOfMemoryError's.

Comment: Yes, it will be made configurable, but really want that feature.

Answer (score 0):

For making it infinite you can set it to a very long value:-

```
 webSSOProfileConsumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```